# How to Get all the pending tasks and purge queue in Pika RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, queue, pika

I want to get all the pending tasks in the queue to save in database.
and remove those tasks from the queue.

I know `channel.purgeQueue` but it will only remove them.

I need to know the pending tasks in the queue.

How to get them

Answer (score 5):

Simply

```py
channel.queue_purge(queue_name)
```

[pika docs](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.queue_purge)

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic RabbitMQ functionality, please read this:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

The code you are looking of is:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] Received %r" % (body,)
    ### PUT_YOUR_CODE_HERE
    print " [x] Done"
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello')
```

When you execute the `ch.basic_ack` the message is removed from the queue

Comment: I want to run some function in the consumer when main purge is called in order to persist its messages.

Comment: @ShanKhan is enough to put your code inside the callback, I modified the answer